# how to check if unknown object partly covers the object i want to detect

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, object-detection, yolo

I want to detect an object from an image,I use yolo object detection. I detect car from the image. I consider the case when another unknown object partly covers it, how can my program know that there is another object on the top.

I use YOLO detection. I detect car in the image. I consider the case when there is for example a person in the middle of the camera and the car, and the person partly covers the car. Yolo still can recognize that there is a car in the image, but I want to separate such cases.

Can I use semantic segmentation in this case?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ok I use YOLO detection. I detect car in the image. I consider the case when there is  for example a person in the middle of the camera and the car, and the person partly covers the car. Yolo still can recognize that there is a car in the image, but I want to separate such cases.